# Jenkinsfile sharing variable globally

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Jenkinsfile

```
node {
  checkout scm; 
  def config = readFile 'subdir/file'
}


pipeline {
   agent any
   environment {
     tgt = "${config.tgt}"                <---- config is not available
   }
}
```

I am getting the error
`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: config for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

So, how can ensure that config variable is seen?

Side note:
we used to use readTrusted as seen below but we cant use it because it's doing a lightweight checkout. And we cant use gerrit trigger variable GERRIT_REFSPEC for lightweight checkout

```
def config = readTrusted 'subdir/file'
pipeline {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a similar example like your scenario would be

```
def config
node {
  config = [tgt: "/home"]
}


pipeline {
   agent any;
   environment { 
       CC = 'clang'
       tgt = "${config.tgt}"
   }
   stages {
      
       stage('debug') {
           steps {
               echo CC
               echo tgt
           }
       }
   }
}
```

for your case it would be

```
def config
node {
  checkout scm; 
  config = readFile 'subdir/file'
}


pipeline {
   agent any
   environment {
     tgt = "${config.tgt}"
   }
   stages {
     .....
   }
}
```